# Right syntax to put non hard coded values(variables) in oracle sql select statement in java program

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I got the following error with the below code. **java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ROLLNO": invalid identifier** . I tried roll_no='rollNo'  as well in the select statement but did not work. I would like to know the right syntax in the where clause. roll_no is a column in students of datatype int. rollNo is another int value passed in the method.

```java
public boolean authenticate(int rollNo,String password) {
  String sql = "SELECT password FROM students where roll_no=rollNo"; //this statement giving error
  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
}
```

Comment: What's columns, and what's variables?

Comment: The left part of the comparison is not passed to the DB driver. Replace it with a question mark (?) and pass it as a parameter to the query

Answer (score 3):

Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to make things easier and also to avoid SQL injection.

```
public boolean authenticate(int rollNo,String password) {
    String sql = "SELECT password FROM students where roll_no=?";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);// Where conn is Connection object
    pstmt.setInt(1, rollNo);
    ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(sql);
    //...
}
```